# Filtered Lookup on Created By

Tags: custom-list, lookup-column, filter

I have two lists. First one is a Projects List and Second List has a lookup column to the First list. I want the lookup column on Second list to show only the Projects filtered by the column "Created By".

In example: If John Doe Created a Project in the first list, then, John Doe will go to second list to create a record but The projects lookup column should only show projects created by John Doe and not all other project created by someone else. I am using Sharepoint 2016.

Your support is really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can't you use workflow to create a new item in the second list with Project Name and Author column?

Answer (score 1):

Use Rest Api on New form:

```
$("select[title^='Projects']").empty();

        $("select[title^='Projects']").append("<option value=''></option>");

        var listName='Projects';
        var currentUser='John Doe';
        var Query = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl+ "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/Items?$select=Projects/Title&$expand=Projects&$filter=Author eq '" + currentUser + "' ;

        $.ajax({
            url: Query,
            type: "GET",
            headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {


                    var  jsonData= data.d;
                    var i =0;
                    var listItems="";
                    for (i = 0; i < jsonData.results.length; i++){
                     listItems+= "<option value='" + jsonData.results[i].Title+ "'>" + jsonData.results[i].Title+ "</option>";
                    }
                $("select[title^='Projects']").append(listItems);    

            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                console.log(xhr.status);

            }
        });
```